# How to override a parent classes static variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

How to override a parent classes static variable.

So I have the parent class

```
class DatabaseItem
{
   static int instanceCount;

   DatabaseItem()
   {
     instanceCount++;
   }
};
```

if I have 2 classes that inherit from DatabaseItem, I want each class to record **how many instances of their class only exist**. How do I do this?

So:

```
class Person : public DatabaseItem
{
  // how do I make sure when I make the call  int numOfpeople = Person::instanceCount;
  // that I only get the number of people objects that exist & not all the DatabaseItem
  // objects that exist?
};

class FoodItem : public DatabaseItem
{
  // how do I make sure when I make the call  int numOffoodItems = FoodItem::instanceCount;
  // that I only get the number of FoodItem objects that exist & not all the DatabaseItem
  // objects that exist?
};
```

---

**EDIT** In response to comments

Yeah but, the above is just an example, if I do this then I have alot of repeating code...

So:

```
    class DatabaseItem
{
    public:
        static unsigned int instanceCount;
        static Vector <unsigned int> usedIDs;

        unsigned int ID;

        DatabaseItem()
        {
            ID = nextAvailableID();
            usedIDs.add( ID );
            DatabaseItem::instanceCount++;
        }

        DatabaseItem( unsigned int nID )
        {
            if ( isIDFree( nID ) )
            {
                ID = nID;
            }
            else ID = nextAvailableID();

            usedIDs.add( ID );
            DatabaseItem::instanceCount++;
        }

        bool isIDFree( unsigned int nID )
        {
            // This is pretty slow to check EVERY element

            for (int i=0; i<usedIDs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (usedIDs[i] == nID)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        unsigned int nextAvailableID()
        {
            unsigned int nID = 0;

            while ( true )
            {
                if ( isIDFree( ID ) )
                {
                    return nID;
                }
                else nID++;
            }
        }
};


class Person    {
    public:
        static unsigned int instanceCount;
        static Vector <unsigned int> usedIDs;

        unsigned int ID;

        Person()
        {
            ID = nextAvailableID();
            usedIDs.add( ID );
            Person::instanceCount++;
        }

        Person( unsigned int nID )
        {
            if ( isIDFree( nID ) )
            {
                ID = nID;
            }
            else ID = nextAvailableID();

            usedIDs.add( ID );
            Person::instanceCount++;
        }

        bool isIDFree( unsigned int nID )
        {
            // This is pretty slow to check EVERY element

            for (int i=0; i<usedIDs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (usedIDs[i] == nID)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        unsigned int nextAvailableID()
        {
            unsigned int nID = 0;

            while ( true )
            {
                if ( isIDFree( ID ) )
                {
                    return nID;
                }
                else nID++;
            }
        }
};
```

.. then I have to rewrite the same code for FoodItem, coffeeRun....

Comment: Create a static for each derived class..no need to override.

Comment: You don't override it, but you can _hide_ it by creating a variable of the same name in a derived class.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal What about if I make DatbaseItem's variables virtual? So virtual static unsigned int instanceCount; ? So the sub-classer HAS to create a variable of this?

Comment: @Mack: Function members can be virtual, not data members.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Thanks for the reply. Is there any other option to solve my problem?

Comment: @Mack: There's no other way to go about what you've asked, but you never really stated your wider problem. I suspect you don't _really_ need to count instances of specific types...

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Actually your right I dont really need to count instances, but I do need to track unique object ID's using a class static vector that records all the used id's so far just for that sub-class

Comment: Is it really necessary to separate those on a per-class basis?  It would be easier just to let them all share a single pool of unique IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Use templates to get away with all such problems of updating instance count in every constructor etc.

```
template<class T>
struct Instance
{
  static unsigned int count;
  Instance () { count ++; }
  Instance (const Instance& o) { count ++; }
};
template<class T>
unsigned int Instance<T>::count = 0;
```

Now this template can be inherited by any of the classes, which you need to get counted for their instances:

```
class DatabaseItem : public Instance<DatabaseItem> {};
class Person : public DatabaseItem, Instance<Person> {};
class FoodItem : public DatabaseItem, Instance<FoodItem> {};
```

That's it!

Whenever a class object is declared, it will do its job. It can be used as following:

```
DatabaseItem *pD = new DatabaseItem[5];
Person obj[10];
cout<<Instance<DatabaseItem>::count<<endl;  // 5 + 10 = 15
cout<<Instance<Person>::count<<endl;        // 10
```

You don't have to update count anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to have a static variable in the base class and tell from it how many derived class instances of each type are present. Instead, have a static class variable in each class that gets incremented in the constructor.

```
class Person : public DatabaseItem
{
     static int numPersonItems ;
     Person()
     {
         ++numPersonItems ;
     }
};

int DatabaseItem::numPersonItems = 0 ;
```

`numPersonItems` is the number of `Person` instances. Similarly can be done for the `FoodItem` class too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't rely on virtual dispatch in a base class constructor, you need to either provide the static information directly to it as a parameter, or provide the derived class to it so it can query the static information itself.  The latter is illustrated below

```
struct Base { 
    //provide whatever actual interface you need your type to have here
    virtual ~Base();
};

template<typename Derived>
struct Intermediate : Base {
    Intermediate() {
        Derived::var++;  //doesn't rely on polymorphism so ok in constructor
    }
};

struct Derived : Intermediate<Derived> {
    static int var;
};
```

Given your specific use case, I would be inclined to not do this at all, however, and either have the base class disperse unique IDs to all instances, regardless of type, or move the ID creation into a separate class/method outright, and query it for a unique identifier:

```
template<typename T>
struct UniqueID { 
    static some64bitIntType GetID(); //possibly non-static, lots of ways to handle this
};

struct Object {
    some64bitIntType ID;
    Object() : ID(UniqueID<Object>::GetID()) { }
};
```

Or something along those lines. Personally, I'd be inclined not to bother with releasing IDs back to be reused.  Its a *lot* of extra work, with little practical gain unless you're trying to limit yourself to a relatively small number of instances.